# Structure column in Aquamacs

Tags: aquamacs

I am exploring Aquamacs for Latex, and I wonder if there's an option to show a column next to the buffer with listed the structure/tree of the document (chapters, sections, paragraphs, etc.) similar to what appears in Texmaker.

Comment: If you are using `reftex`, which I think is standard in Aquamacs, then `C-=` in the tex buffer will pop up another buffer with the table of contents.  There is also a `Ref` menu to choose other commands from the `reftex` package.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually found it in the dropdown menu... I needed just to click on "Ref"->"Table of Contents".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to come down to a feature request for a particular editor.